# Laravel. Ошибка в маршрутах

Tags: php, laravel, route, blade

Ошибка в шаблоне blade: **Route [admin.products.index] not defined.**

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return redirect('admin/dashboard');
    })->name('admin.dashboard');

    Route::get('dashboard', function() {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    })->name('admin.dashboard');

    Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);

    Route::get('categories', function() {
        return view('admin.categories');
    })->name('admin.categories');

    Route::get('reviews', function() {
        return view('admin.reviews');
    })->name('admin.reviews');

});
```

**layout.blade.php**

```
<div class="sidebar-content">
                        <div class="nav-container">
                            <nav id="main-menu-navigation" class="navigation-main">
                                <div class="nav-lavel">Navigation</div>
                                <div class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}"><i class="ik ik-bar-chart-2"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.products.index') }}"><i class="ik ik-shopping-cart"></i><span>Products</span></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.categories') }}"><i class="ik ik-grid"></i><span>Categories</span></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.reviews') }}"><i class="ik ik-filter"></i><span>Reviews</span></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="../index.html"><i class="ik ik-book-open"></i><span>Blogs</span></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="../index.html"><i class="ik ik-user"></i><span>Users</span></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="../index.html"><i class="ik ik-settings"></i><span>Settings</span></a>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Проблема исправлена. Указал вручную методы контроллера:

```
Route::resource('products', ProductController::class, [
        'names' => [
            'index' => 'admin.products.index',
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: Метод index в контроллере присутствует.

Comment: ну а в маршрутах то отсутствует. или resuorce именнованные создает?

Comment: Насколько я знаю ресурсы сами создают маршруты: index, create, editи тд.

Comment: `group` зато наверное не учитывает

Comment: `artisan route:list` посмотрите что выдает по этому поводу